# Style React component to appear in the middle of semantic-ui grid column

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using semantic-ui and am trying to centre my `Animation` component in the middle of my div, so it should say 'protect your data' in the middle of the right-hand grid column, though I'm very new to React/Javascript/Front-end world so can't figure out how to best do this!

I'm using grid to ensure the App is mobile friendly, so using simple css like `left: "70%"; top: "50%"` isn't quite what I'm looking for.
Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Deal.js

```
import React from "react";
import Timer from "./Timer";
import Animation from "./Animation";
import deal from "./Deal.css";

class Deal extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ui vertically divided grid">
                <div className="two column row">
                    <div className="column">
                        <h3>DEAL ENDS IN:</h3>
                        <Timer endTime="april 18, 2020 12:00:00" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Animation />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Deal;
```

Comment: Yeah. Definitely, you have to create a grid layout as your expectation. It's not that difficult. Let me see what can I do for you. You need to have an exact view like you have shown here. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be help.

```
class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
  <div class="ui four column grid">
    <div
      class="row"
      style={{
        height: "150px",
        backgroundColor: "bisque"
      }}
    >
      <div
        class="eight wide column"
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ margin: "0px" }}>
          <h3>DEAL ENDS IN:</h3>
          <div
            style={{
              height: "50px",
              width: "200px",
              backgroundColor: "red"
            }}
          >
            Timer Component
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="eight wide column"
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ margin: "0px" }}>
          <h1>protect your data</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="wide centered column">Animation Component</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

You just have to replace my contents here. It is all about designing the grid. There is no need to have a react experience for that. If something need to be corrected, put a comment.

Comment: Thank you - I tried this out but it doesn't look quite right. Here's what I'm trying to achieve: https://imgur.com/a/ykVwfFF
I've looked at the semantic-ui documentation about adjusting alignment (https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#significant-word-order) thought I haven't found a combination that comes close to what I want

Comment: I checked your design and I made a sandbox for that. Check now. I think now it must be correct. However, just using the framework wasn't enough. Did some css changes too.https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-poincare-2el6d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Amazing thank you for writing this up - it's just what I needed! :)